# upload image on a parallel directory's folder

Tags: php

I have two directories:

1. /publichtml
2. /csp.example.com

My code is in `csp.example.com/classes/ep-class.php` and I want to upload my file on `/publichtml/upload/photo` folder. How can I achieve that also `/publichtml` is accessible using `example.com` so I am taking target directory as a absolute url?

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_FILES["imagefile"]["type"][0]))
{
    $filename=$_FILES["imagefile"]["name"][0];
    // Storing source path of the file in a variable
    $sourcePath = $_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'][0];
    // Target path where file is to be stored 
    $targetPath = SITEURL."upload/photo/".$filename; 

    if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath))
    {
        return "Yes";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $_FILES["imagefile"]["errors"][0];
        die("File upload error !");
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: use a full system path

Comment: @Fred -ii- Like example.com/images/upload

Comment: No, as and for example: `/var/usr/x_folder/` - if in public, then `/var/usr/public/folder/`

Comment: Ok thanks i am trying and will update...

Comment: @Fred-ii-  i tried to upload it as /home/example/public_html/uploads/images bt it wasn't uploaded.

Comment: Fixed syntax issue of closing curly brace

Comment: @Parfait Actually i pasted partial code.My issue is not with the syntax rather than the logic of file being uploaded...